# Using conditional join points in spring

Tags: java, spring, aop, pointcuts, aspect

How do we use conditional join points in spring

In my requirement, the point cut has to be applied if the  **method name is insert OR the method name is update OR  method  name is delete AND the method should have exactly three arguments**

This was the code I wrote,

```
  <aop:config>
    <aop:aspect  ref="auditAOP">
        <aop:pointcut id="insert" expression="execution(* .IbatisDAOSupportImpl.insert(*,*,*))" />
        <aop:pointcut id="delete" expression="execution(* IbatisDAOSupportImpl.delete(*,*,*))" />
        <aop:pointcut id="update" expression="execution(* IbatisDAOSupportImpl.update(*,*,*))" />
        <aop:pointcut id="auditInsertUpdateOrDelete" expression="insert || delete || update"/>
        <aop:after method="afterInsertUpdateOrDelete" pointcut-ref="auditInsertUpdateOrDelete"/>
    </aop:aspect>

</aop:config>
```

There is something wrong with the below line; I get an error saying the expression is not well formed.

```
    <aop:pointcut id="auditInsertUpdateOrDelete" expression="insert || delete || update"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a complex pointcut which contains all the logic in a single expression. You are trying to refer to your other pointcuts within your expression, which just doesn't work.

You need to do something like this:

```
<aop:config>
  <aop:aspect  ref="auditAOP">
    <aop:pointcut id="auditInsertUpdateOrDelete" expression="within(*.IbatisDAOSupportImpl)
                     and (execution( * insert*(..)) or 
                     execution( * delete*(..))  or 
                     execution( * update*(..)))"/>
    <aop:after method="afterInsertUpdateOrDelete" pointcut-ref="auditInsertUpdateOrDelete"/>
  </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

Here is a good reference for building complex expressions: 
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?37596-complex-pointcut-expressions